# I have to press a button twice to fill react state from firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my react component, when the component mounts, I want to run the loadData() function to populate an array of people objects in the state.

This component is called UserDisplaySection.js

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.loadData();
}
```

Which calls the function to load data:

```
loadData = () => {
    const db = fire.database();
    const ref = db.ref('User');

    let currentState = this.state.people;
    ref.on('value', (snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach( (data) => {
        const currentStudent = data.val();
        let user ={
          "email" : currentStudent.Email,
          "name": currentStudent.Name,
          "age": currentStudent.Age,
          "location": currentStudent.Location,
          "course": currentStudent.Course,
          "interests": currentStudent.Interests
        }
        currentState.push(user);

      });
    });

    this.setState({
      people: currentState
    });

  }
```

From another component called Home.js, I render UserDisplaySection.js with the toggle of a button which sets the state of a boolean called willDisplayUser which is initialised as false by default.

```
handleDisplayUsers = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      willDisplayUsers: !(this.state.willDisplayUsers),

    });
  }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <button className="mainButtons" onClick={this.handleDisplayUsers}>View Users</button> <br />
            {this.state.willDisplayUsers ? <UserDisplaySection/>: null}

          </div>
        );

  }
```

Note: The function works and populates the state with the correct data, but only after I render the UserDisplaySection.js component for a second time and works perfectly until I reload the page.

Comment: What is "this.state.willDisplayUsers" initial value, before you "negate" it on that last setState?

Comment: @FrederikMoller I’m on mobile now on the way home but I believe it’s set to false. Using react dev tools I can see that the component mounts and does actually render, but the array is still empty until I re render it by toggling the butting again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the problem is that you are setting state outside of the `ref.on` callback.

Data fetch is async and the callback will be executed later in time. Since set state is outside the callback, it gets called called immediately after registering a listener, but before the data finished fetching. That's why it does not work on initial render/button click: it shows initial state, not waiting for the fetch to finish.

Also, using `once` instead of `on` might serve better for your case.

```
loadData = () => {
    const db = fire.database();
    const ref = db.ref('User');

    let currentState = this.state.people;
    ref.once('value', (snapshot) => {
      // callback start
      snapshot.forEach( (data) => {
        const currentStudent = data.val();
        let user ={
          "email" : currentStudent.Email,
          "name": currentStudent.Name,
          "age": currentStudent.Age,
          "location": currentStudent.Location,
          "course": currentStudent.Course,
          "interests": currentStudent.Interests
        }
        currentState.push(user);
      });

      this.setState({
        people: currentState
      });
      // callback end
    });

    // setState used to be here, outside of the callback
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

By doing `ref.on()` you are actually declaring a listener that "listens for data changes at a particular location", as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on). The "callback will be triggered for the initial data and again whenever the data changes". In other words it is disconnected from your button `onClick` event.

If you want to fetch data on demand, i.e. when your button is clicked, you should use the [`once()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once) method instead, which "listens for exactly one event of the specified event type, and then stops listening".